# Mock default export function with inbuilt node test runner

Tags: node.js, node-test-runner

I'm using the inbuilt [node test runner](https://nodejs.org/api/test.html), and I'm unable to mock functions that are exported in a reasonable way.

Let's start with the workaround I've found. If I export a function in this way:

`wretchedExportSyntax.js`

```js
function wretchedExportSyntax() {
  return false;
}

export default {
  wretchedExportSyntax
}
```

Then I can write a test that mocks the function fairly easily:

`index.test.js`

```js
import { test, mock } from 'node:test';
import assert from 'node:assert';

import wretchedExportSyntax from './wretchedExportSyntax.js';

function wrapper() {
  return wretchedExportSyntax.wretchedExportSyntax();
}

test('wretched export syntax', () => {
  mock.method(wretchedExportSyntax, 'wretchedExportSyntax', () => true);
  assert.equal(wretchedExportSyntax.wretchedExportSyntax(), true);
})

test('wrapper function that calls wretched export', () => {
  mock.method(wretchedExportSyntax, 'wretchedExportSyntax', () => true);
  assert.equal(wrapper(), true);
})
```

However, if my file has only one function, I would much prefer to export it in the following way:

`defaultExport.js`

```js
export default function () {
  return false;
}
```

It's not a method, so I can't use `mock.method()`, and `mock.fn()` does not seem to work the way I understand it.

```js
import defaultExport from './defaultExport.js'
test.skip('default export syntax', (t) => {
  t.mock.fn(defaultExport, () => true); // Doesn't work
  assert.equal(defaultExport(), true);
})
```

I've built a reduced test case here, but this issue is relevant both for functions I'm writing, as well as functions I don't have control over, like `knex()`.

How do you mock a function that is default export using the native node test runner?

Comment: I'm hitting the same problem, and FYI I've opened an issue describing this on nodejs/help: https://github.com/nodejs/help/issues/4298

Comment: Same issue. Function just doesn't get mocked. Even if you export it as `export async function wretchedExportSyntax () {}`

Answer (score 0):

I referenced this question in the following issue: https://github.com/nodejs/help/issues/4298

The workaround we found since we're using CJS is to leverage this library, waiting for an official way to mock modules: https://github.com/mhweiner/cjs-mock